# html5 canvas aspect ratio?

Tags: javascript

In html5 canvas element use I have a problem with default aspect ratio.
The default aspect ratio for the canvas element in Firefox and Safari, at least
appears to be 2/1 for width and height. This is the only combination of height
and width that will produce a 1:1 aspect ration for rectangle drawn to the
canvas element.

So, how do I set the aspect ratio for the canvas element that will allow
a 1:1 ratio for items drawn to it?

I have an account with Coding Forums and have not gotten an adequate response.
I have obtained some print texts on the subject but they do not address this.
I have been programming javascript/html/css for at least 10 years.

I hope I'm not stuck with a unalterable default ratio.

Looking over the list of similar questions, I don't see this particular issue addressed.

Comment: What is te exact issue? Is the problem that if the width/height ratio is not 2/1, a square drawn onto it programmatically will not result in a square on-screen? If not, please explain.

Answer (score 1):

The Canvas can have it's own width and height which is independent of the Dom element.
This is causing the non 1:1 aspect ratio.

To fix you need to set the width and height attributes to match the width and height of the dom containing element.

For example, in jquery you can do the following.

$('canvas').attr('width', '100').attr('height', '100');

This will make your canvas a 100 pixel square. Assuming this is in a dom element with matching width and height properties then you'll get 1:1 aspect ratio.